# Are there names for the measurements of an arrow?

Tags: single-word-requests, shapes

I need to describe some measurements of an arrow shape. Are there names for the measurements described in the diagram pictured below? Blue lines indicate a measurement and are capped with red lines.

[image: http://bwroga.com/img/arrow1.jpg]

[image source](http://bwroga.com/img/arrow1.jpg)

Comment: Here's a [link](http://www.ccsd.edu/bardonia/Library/4thwebquests/nativeamerican/studentwork/4A/arrowhead.htm) to a website with an illustration of an arrow and its parts. Might be a useful place to start.

Comment: Did you create this picture or did you get it from somewhere else? If somewhere else, that place would more likely have the vocabulary you seek. If you created it, what tells you that those are the important parts of an arrow and that others will have words for them?

Comment: Why would you think that English has words for such things?

Comment: cf. [Dah - Standardized Method for Point Grading 2001](http://www.pugetsoundknappers.com/interesting_stuff/David_Heath_Articles/David%20Heaths%20Point%20Grading%20Method.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a proposed list of terms based on these diagrams of an [arrowhead](http://www.ccsd.edu/bardonia/Library/4thwebquests/nativeamerican/studentwork/4A/arrowhead.htm) and an [arrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Arrow.svg):

[image: arrowhead] [image: arrow]

- A: head length
- B: tip-to-neck length
- C: shaft length
- D: ear length
- E: ear width
- F: head width
- G: nock depth
- H: fletching or shaft width

However, most people won't be familiar with these perhaps other than arrowhead and shaft, so if you use them it would be good to include a labelled diagram.

Comment: So are you (intelligently) guessing or do you have an authority on arrow construction?

Comment: Neither, just suggesting some terms as I'm not sure if they already exist.